# Object insert issue in JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, insert, indexing

I have a JavaScript array like below:

```
[
    {type: 'text', name: 'title', id: 'title', placeholder: 'Type here'},
    {type: 'textarea', name: 'description', id: 'description', placeholder: 'Type here'}
]
```

Now I want to inset `{type: 'text', name: 'age', id: 'age', placeholder: 'Type here'}` after first object. So my final result set will be looks like:

```
[
    {type: 'text', name: 'title', id: 'title', placeholder: 'Type here'},
    {type: 'text', name: 'age', id: 'age', placeholder: 'Type here'}
    {type: 'textarea', name: 'description', id: 'description', placeholder: 'Type here'}
]
```

I want in plain JavaScript or jQuery!

Comment: Kindly post your attempt(s).

Comment: I have tried with push but it always add at the end!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

like this:

```
var a = [
    {type: 'text', name: 'title', id: 'title', placeholder: 'Type here'},
    {type: 'textarea', name: 'description', id: 'description', placeholder: 'Type here'}
]

var b= {type: 'text', name: 'age', id: 'age', placeholder: 'Type here'} 

a.splice(1,0,b);

console.log(a)
```

Comment: This would actually have to be `a.splice(1,0,b)`

Answer (score 5):

If your array is in variable `array`, then:

```
array.splice(1, 0, {
    type: 'text',
    name: 'age',
    id: 'age',
    placeholder: 'Type here'
});
```

The `1` means that you want to place it at index `1`, `0` means you want to delete `0` items from the array. See [splice documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), it is quite the abomination of a method with 2 purposes of which both are never used at the same time :D

Answer (score -1):

If you want that object at that exact position, use the `splice` method.

```
var myArray = [{
  type: 'text',
  name: 'title',
  id: 'title',
  placeholder: 'Type here'
}, {
  type: 'textarea',
  name: 'description',
  id: 'description',
  placeholder: 'Type here'
}];
var myObject = {
  type: 'text',
  name: 'age',
  id: 'age',
  placeholder: 'Type here'
};
myArray.push(myObject);
```

Comment: this will add the required object at the last of the array.

Comment: Did you read my edit? Please don't be so forthcoming.